# Concatenate strings from a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-3.5

I want to concatenate a string from a 2d `numpy` array like this,

```
for x in np.ndindex(mat.shape[0]):
    concat = ""
    for y in range(len(columns)):
        concat += str(mat[x][2 + y])
```

where `mat` is a 2d array containing `string`s or `int`s in each cell, `columns` is a list of column names for `mat`, e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, using `mat[x][2 + y]` to avoid concatenating strings from the 1st two columns. I am wondering what is the best way to do it, probably in a more concise/efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been a little vague in your definition of *concatenate* — I hope that the following is enough to get you started

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in row[2:]) for row in mat))
```

The external `join` joins the rows with a newline, the internal one joins
*a few* of the elements of each row in `mat` — if you are not after ALL the elements except the first two, modify to please you the upper limit of the slice...

Note that `str(x)` leaves string elements undisturbed and formats numeric items in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

*Ab*-using the fact that we are dealing with a `2D` array, we can resort to just one loop -

```
["".join(i) for i in mat[:,2:].astype(str)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: mat
Out[143]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]])

In [144]: ["".join(i) for i in mat[:,2:].astype(str)]
Out[144]: ['0311', '1110', '1211']
```